# ¿Qué diferencia hay entre "percha" y "perchero"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, cuba

En mi país, Cuba, hasta donde he oído se usa `percha` y `perchero` para referirse a ese objeto donde se cuelga la ropa, usando indistintamente ambos términos.

Para mí percha es donde se cuelga la ropa y perchero es donde se cuelgan las perchas, o esa es la idea que tengo. Quizás el término `perchero` no sea muy conocido, pero yo si lo he oído muchas veces, por lo menos en mi país. Vivo en Holguin, Cuba.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

El DRAE incluye "[perchero](http://dle.rae.es/?id=SXTmTs7)"

> perchero
>
> 1. m. Conjunto de perchas.
> 2. m. Lugar en que hay perchas.
> 3. m. percha (‖ pieza con colgaderos para la ropa).

Hay 13 entradas para  "[percha](http://dle.rae.es/?id=SXM0KKz)", entre ellas

> 1. f. Pieza o mueble de madera o metal con colgaderos en que se pone ropa, sombreros u otros objetos, y que puede estar sujeto a la pared o constar de un palo largo y de un pie para que apoye en el suelo.
> 2. f. Utensilio ligero que consta de un soporte donde se cuelga un traje u otra prenda parecida y que tiene en su parte superior un gancho para suspenderlo de una percha o de una barra.

Por lo que entiendo que por percha te puedes referir a un tipo de mueble, donde colgar sombreros o abrigos (un *coat rack*), por ejemplo.

[image]

Yo a este utensilio le habría dicho siempre `perchero`, pero parece que puede ser descrito con la definición de `percha` del DRAE. Idem para algo como

[image]

**Conclusión**: Yo pensaba lo mismo, que la *percha* es la pieza de madera con un gancho donde poner una camisa, por ejemplo, y que el *perchero* es otro lugar donde poner más ropa o perchas, pero según esas definiciones del diccionario, ambos términos son hasta cierto punto "intercambiables".

Comment: @walen, buen apunte, cuando el DRAE dice que "perchero" puede ser una "percha" (tercera entrada) se refiere a la entrada primera de "perchero" ("Pieza o mueble de madera o metal con colgaderos [...]  que puede estar sujeto a la pared o constar de un palo largo") y no a la segunda ("Utensilio ligero [...] que tiene en su parte superior un gancho"). Bien visto. Gracias por el apunte.

Comment: Curioso por cierto que se usa "percha" en la definición de "percha". "Una _percha_ es un utensilio que se puede colgar de una _percha_" :-)

Answer (score 2):

Para complementar la muy bien documentada [respuesta de Diego](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/21347/1674), es importante notar que el Diccionario de americanismos recoge una acepción específica de tu país, Cuba:

> [**percha**](http://lema.rae.es/damer/srv/search?id=Fu5Q5CHDJx0AyKYMnYi).
>   I.  1.  f. ES, Cu, Ve, Ur. Conjunto de prendas de vestir, especialmente las elegantes y costosas.
>   **2.    Cu, PR. Armario sin puertas para colgar ropa.**
>   3.  RD. Lujo y ostentación en el vestir. pop.
>   II. 1.  Gu, Ho. prensa, multitud o montón.
>   III.    1.  f. Ch. Sarta de pescados o mariscos.
>   IV. 1.  f. Ho. Conjunto de tablas puestas verticalmente para el secado.
>   2.  Ho. Rama seca de un árbol.
>   V.  1.  adj/sust. Ec. Referido a mujer, solterona.
>   ▶   echar ~; quedarse en la ~; tirar ~; tirarse la ~.

Es decir, algo así:

[image]

[*Perchero*](http://lema.rae.es/damer/srv/search?id=rWO4UTajvx0AKl2avDv) aparece en dicho diccionario pero con una acepción propia de Ecuador, por lo que entiendo que en Cuba su uso es el estándar que recoge el DLE:

> [**percha**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=SXM0KKz)
>   Del fr. perche o del cat. perxa, y estos del lat. pertĭca 'pértiga'.
>   1. f. Pieza o mueble de madera o metal con colgaderos en que se pone ropa, sombreros u otros objetos, y que puede estar sujeto a la pared o constar de un palo largo y de un pie para que apoye en el suelo.

---

Yendo un poco más allá, el NTLLE me descube que la palabra *perchero* es muy nueva, ¡apenas tiene cien años! En efecto, su primera referencia en diccionarios es del 1918 de Rodríguez Navas:

> Mueble o utensilio de madera o metal, formado por un soporte con varias perchas, para colgar ropas u otros objetos.

Por contra, percha viene de lejos (de hecho del latín *pertĭca* -*pértiga*- a través del francés o el catalán).

Lo que me sugiere que lo de *mueble de madera* es una acepción que ha ido cogiendo consistencia con el tiempo y que, tal y como concluye Diego, puede ser sinónimo de *percha*.

> [**perchero**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=SXTmTs7)
>   1. m. Conjunto de perchas.
>   2. m. Lugar en que hay perchas.
>   3. m. percha (‖ pieza con colgaderos para la ropa).